# ProgressBar in Toolbar (as Actionbar) is not shown (visible) on Android lollipop (5.0) using AppCompat v21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-progressbar

My `ProgressBar` isn't shown in Android Lollipop (5.0), works fine with Android 4.4. Any suggestions?

Here's my code which sets a `Toolbar` in `onCreate`:

```
super.onCreate...
setContentView...

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: try removing the toolbar theme!

Comment: thx.. it was a theme problem.

Comment: What is a toolbar theme? I am facing the same issue..